# TOPN with condition based on a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am a beginner with Power BI. I have a table that looks something like this in Power BI Desktop but it has more sensors and more data points:

| Seconds | Sensor | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2887 | 23 |
| 1 | 2887 | 25 |
| 2 | 2887 | 42 |
| 3 | 2887 | 45 |
| 0 | 2879 | 87 |
| 1 | 2879 | 56 |
| 2 | 2879 | 54 |
| 3 | 2879 | 34 |
| 0 | 2845 | 64 |
| 1 | 2845 | 63 |
| 2 | 2845 | 46 |
| 3 | 2845 | 97 |

It's a time series data and it's in this structure for calculation purposes. My goal is to:

1. Calculate the average for every second among all sensors, so I end up with 4 averages.
2. Calculate the moving average for every 2 seconds
3. Then get the difference between every consecutive second
4. Lastly get the number of the second (0,1,2 or 3) with the highest difference amount

**5) Get the number of the next highest second with a condition that this value must happens in at least 2 seconds after the first highest. If the first highest is 0 then then the second highest will be at least 2 seconds away from it.** This step is the one I am having trouble with.

These are the measures I am using right now, they work except for number 5 in the list above. Any help will be appreciated.

**Here is the average value per second measure**

```
    AverageValuePerSecond = 
        AVERAGEX(
            VALUES('All Rep Sensors (2)'[Seconds ]), 
            CALCULATE(
                AVERAGE('All Rep Sensors (2)'[Value])
            )
        )
```

**This measure is to get the moving average**

```
MovingAvgeragePer2Seconds = 
VAR cur_second =
    SELECTEDVALUE('Main Table'[Seconds])
VAR tmp =
    FILTER(ALL('Main Table'), 'Main Table'[Seconds] <= cur_second && 'Main Table'[Seconds] > cur_second - 2)
RETURN
    AVERAGEX(tmp, [AverageValuePerSecond])
```

**And this measure to get the difference:**

```
DifferenceBetweenAverages2Seconds = 
    VAR CurrentAverage = [MovingAvgeragePer2Seconds]
    VAR PreviousAverage =
        CALCULATE(
            [MovingAvgeragePer2Seconds],
            FILTER(
                ALL('Table'[Seconds ]),
                'Table'[Seconds ] = MAX('Table'[Seconds ]) - 1
            )
        )
    RETURN
        IF(ISBLANK(PreviousAverage), 0, ABS(CurrentAverage - PreviousAverage))
```

**And this one is to get the first highest:**

```
MaxMovingAverageSecond = 
CALCULATE(
    VALUES('Table'[Seconds ]),
    TOPN(1, VALUES('Table'[Seconds ]), [DifferenceBetweenAverages2Seconds], DESC)
)
```

**And this is my attempt for the second highest, but it isn't working:**

```
NextMaxMovingAverageSecond = 
VAR FirstMaxSecond = [MaxMovingAverageSecond]
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Table'[Seconds ]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Table'[Seconds ]),
            [DifferenceBetweenAverages10econds] > 0 &&
            'Table'[Seconds ] > FirstMaxSecond + 2 &&
            'Table'[Seconds ] <> FirstMaxSecond
        )
    )
```

Update: The most help I need is with the last measure, it is not working and  I am not sure how to write the condition. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey Sam, Using the line chart with the Seconds as X-axis and the measure itself as Y-axis, I can see the values of the measures but when i try to view them in a table it won't work. I am using seconds and the measure as a columns in the table. This applies to the measure MovingAverage10Seconds and DifferenceBetweenAverages10econds

Comment: Thanks for that. Curious, will this always be 0, 1, 2, 3 seconds or simplified for this question? As in, why "10Seconds" in the measure names?

Comment: Yes, I have around 10 sensors and 540 points for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original fix for original question**
Update your `MovingAverage10Seconds` measure to:

```
MovingAverage10Seconds = 
  CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('Table'[Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Seconds ] >= MIN('Table'[Seconds ]) - 2 &&
        'Table'[Seconds ] <= MIN('Table'[Seconds ])
    )
  )
```

Note the change from `VALUES` to `MIN`. One value needs to be returned for the conditional to work. You could also change it to `SELECTEDVALUE`. You should find that the fix for `MovingAverage10Seconds` means now you can also view it in a table.

**Updated answer for updated question for measure No. 5**

```
NextMaxMovingAverageSecond = 
  var firstMaxSecond = [MaxMovingAverageSecond]
  return CALCUALTE(
    [MaxMovingAverageSecond],
    'Table'[Seconds ] >= firstMaxSecond + 2
  )
```

Comment: Hey Sam,  I can view the tables now after the edits you shared and I realize now that the moving average is not working properly. It's taking the average for all the previous points instead of only all the last 10 seconds (2 seconds in the example I shared). And the NextMaxMovingAverageSecond  is returning the last second I have in the time series which is not what's expected.

Comment: Hey Sam, please see the update in my question, I was able to make all the measures work except for the last one.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly.