# Comparing column values with a TOPN measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI. I have a measure that returns TOPN values based on another measure like the following:

```
MaxMovingAverageSecond = TOPN(1,
    VALUES('Main Table'[Seconds]), 
    [DifferenceBetweenAverages10Seconds], 
    DESC)
```

And now I am trying to find the next highest value based on a condition. The condition is that the seconds should be 30 points higher than the value in the measure MaxMovingAverageSecond.

The following measure is my attempt to find the second highest value:

```
NextMaxMovingAverageSecond = 
CALCULATE(
    VALUES('Main Table'[Seconds]),
    TOPN(
        1, 
        FILTER(
            ALL('Main Table'[Seconds]),
            'Main Table'[Seconds] > [MaxMovingAverageSecond] +30
        ),
        [DifferenceBetweenAverages10Seconds],
        DESC
    )
)
```

It returns a blank value but it works when I replace the MaxMovingAverageSecond with any integer. So, it works with:

```
            'Main Table'[Seconds] > 200
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this related to question: [TOPN with condition based on a measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77546428/topn-with-condition-based-on-a-measure) ?

```
NextMaxMovingAverageSecond = 
  var firstMaxSecond = [MaxMovingAverageSecond]
  return CALCUALTE(
    [MaxMovingAverageSecond],
    'Table'[Seconds ] > firstMaxSecond + 30
  )
```

Comment: Yes, but this was a specific one about the comparison. Thanks for the help Sam.